# AWS JAVA SDK Generated code not passing parameters

Tags: aws-lambda, command-line-interface, aws-api-gateway

I have a few APIs which I built on AWS and they are accessible though the AWS API Gateway. Currently they are being used by a Web App that I have deployed through AWS AMplify.

I have also built a CLI and wanted to call the APIs from there too. So I went to the API Gateway and generated the code which would allow this to work. Howvever the Lambda logs show that the request paramaters for 2 parameters are not being passed. Could someone please help

When I run my integration test locally I get the following exception

> com.company.sdk.model.TechResourcesClientException: Internal server error
> at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1811)
> at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleServiceErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1395)
> at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1371)
> at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1145)
> at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:802)
> at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
> at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
> at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:704)
> at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
> at com.amazonaws.client.ClientHandlerImpl.doInvoke(ClientHandlerImpl.java:204)
> at com.amazonaws.client.ClientHandlerImpl.invoke(ClientHandlerImpl.java:185)
> at com.amazonaws.client.ClientHandlerImpl.execute(ClientHandlerImpl.java:93)
> at com.amazonaws.opensdk.protect.client.SdkClientHandler.execute(SdkClientHandler.java:42)
> at

My test code looks like the below

```
 TechResourcesClientClientBuilder clientBuilder = TechResourcesClient.builder();


@Test
public void findTechResource() {
    TechResourcesClient client = clientBuilder.connectionConfiguration(new ConnectionConfiguration()
            .maxConnections(100)
            .connectionMaxIdleMillis(1000))
        .timeoutConfiguration(new TimeoutConfiguration()
            .httpRequestTimeout(3000)
            .totalExecutionTimeout(10000)
            .socketTimeout(2000))
        .build();
    
    GetTechresourcesRequest request = new GetTechresourcesRequest("value1", "value2");
    
    
    
    GetTechresourcesResult result = client.getTechresources(request);
    
    
    assertNotNull(result);
    System.out.println("Test 3 passed");
    
    client.shutdown();
}
```

The generated relevant client code looks like the below

```
    @Override
public GetTechresourcesResult getTechresources(GetTechresourcesRequest getTechresourcesRequest) {
    HttpResponseHandler<GetTechresourcesResult> responseHandler = protocolFactory.createResponseHandler(new JsonOperationMetadata().withPayloadJson(true)
            .withHasStreamingSuccessResponse(false), new GetTechresourcesResultJsonUnmarshaller());

    HttpResponseHandler<SdkBaseException> errorResponseHandler = createErrorResponseHandler();

    //RequestConfig requestConfig = null;
    return clientHandler.execute(new ClientExecutionParams<GetTechresourcesRequest, GetTechresourcesResult>()
            .withMarshaller(new GetTechresourcesRequestProtocolMarshaller(protocolFactory)).withResponseHandler(responseHandler)
            .withErrorResponseHandler(errorResponseHandler)
            .withInput(getTechresourcesRequest));
}
```